# Blender: Believeable, animated hose/cable etc

Tags: animation

I want to creat a hose/cable etc., which I can animate.
On the net I found quite a view tutorials, but I didn't found one,
which does it believeable.
With "believeable" I mean:
* The hose/cable does not stretch when one end is moved and the other is not.
* The hose/cable moves equally: If one end moves and the other does not, the hose/cable should not bend strongly in the first view centimeters/inches at the moveing end and keep "frozen in place" for the rest of the 3meters... ;)

And not to forget: I don't want to make a diploma in animation arts for this...:)
Some setups I found were way too complicate and need to be created at 0:0:0.

Is there any way to accomplish that?
Is there an tutorial (which I did'nt found yet). which fits all my needs?

Comment: Soft Body simulation should be able to achieve what you want - see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/how-to-simulate-a-rope/98438 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/how-to-get-the-physics-engine-to-wraps-a-string-around-the-moving-part-of-a-moto/93623. It's important to set the scale of the scene right for realistic interactions with gravity - ie, a 20cm piece of string will behave differently to a 20m cable.

Comment: The problem is: I have a scene, which I dont want to rescale and possible screw up the animation data. I took a look at the blender file at the linked example: The hose looks more like being a noodle than the type of hose I am looking for: Those hoses which connects hydraulic driven parts. Those are barely influenced by gravity but by movements of their ends.

Comment: Can you share your scene or a cut down version of it? It will be easier to provide a solution if I know what limits I’m working to.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8426/935) provide any inspiration?